# Sub-Select query error in SQL Server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

Consider the below query:

```
insert into dbo.SubscriptionDetails (taxonomyid) 
values(select objectid from SubscriptionObjects where objectname=?)
```

This query works fine in my local environment and but gives issues while executed the production environment.

Does the sub-select query needs any properties to be set on the SQL-Server level?

I use Java - JDBC for SQL transactions.

See stack trace below:

```
2013.03.28 15:42:11 CDT ERROR Error while inserting records into SubscriptionDetails table..
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised your version works in any environment!  Try to omit `values`:

```
insert  into dbo.SubscriptionDetails 
        (taxonomyid) 
select  objectid 
from    SubscriptionObjects 
where   objectname=?
```

For more than one subquery, you can:

```
insert  into dbo.SubscriptionDetails 
        (taxonomyid, contenttypeid) 
select  (select objectid from SubscriptionObjects where objectname=?)
,       (select objectid from SubscriptionObjects where objectname=?)
```

Alternatively, use parenthesis to force scalar context with `values`:

```
insert  into dbo.SubscriptionDetails 
        (taxonomyid, contenttypeid) 
values  ((select objectid from SubscriptionObjects where objectname=?),
         (select objectid from SubscriptionObjects where objectname=?))
```

Comment: Apologies, but its a single insert query... select is part of the insert query.

Comment: @TeeGee: when you run this query, are you getting an error or what?

Comment: @Quassnoi - Yes I do, see attached StackTrace. My be its related to data in Production environment. Thanks!

Comment: This is the exact prepared statement I am using in Java... and it works.    insert into dbo.SubscriptionDetails (userid,eventid,taxonomyid,contenttypeid,typeid) values(?,?,"+
       "(select objectid from SubscriptionObjects where objectname=?),"+
       "(select objectid from SubscriptionObjects where objectname=?)," +
       "?)

Comment: @Andomar could you please explain what it means to force scalar context? and Why this error comes up?

Comment: @Quassnoi - Thanks guys! the query gave my Andomar works!! Actually my Production environment was on SQL Server 2005 and not 2008.